# Sphinx Search Result is not displaying value

Tags: php, centos, sphinx

i have configured everything in the sphinx and rotated the indexes also. But when i search the sphinx server(terminal command), it is displaying the matches count only as below, i have no idea on this issue.

```
[root@phpsalzer server]# sudo search -i gplay 'Cut the Rope'
Sphinx 2.0.4-id64-release (r3135)
Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf'...
index 'gplay': query 'Cut the Rope ': returned 2 matches of 2 total in 0.000 sec

displaying matches:
1. document=6, weight=10515
2. document=3, weight=9482

words:
1. 'cut': 5 documents, 15 hits
2. 'the': 72 documents, 2162 hits
3. 'rope': 4 documents, 12 hits
```

In the above result, It is not displaying the document values. Please suggest me on this issue.

Note: i have running the sphinx on the CENTOS with the lates version of sphinx

Comment: This is just the way Sphinx works. It doesn't store raw data. It simply indexes it for search. If you need the raw data, you'll have to hit your database or switch to something like elasticsearch (or any Lucene-based platform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Colin mentions, sphinx doesn't store the raw text that is indexed - known as fields. As not stored can't be returned.

But if you want can store them in attributes, to avoid having to go back to the database.

Attributes can be returned in resultsets

Comment: Yes.. Correct. i have added [sql_attr_uint           = idappsdata
        sql_attr_string         = app_title
        sql_attr_string         = app_id
        sql_attr_float          = app_ratings] in the sphinx.conf, restarted, reindexed the sphinx server. Now i got the above field values app_title, app_id and app_ratings in the result sets.